# Viewer display of SVF files placed in OSS bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge

I uploaded a group of SVF files to the OSS bucket as shown in the image below.
< [uploaded SVF files][1]>
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLEng.png

Even if I call the 0.svf file in this like the html below, it will not be displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Very Basic 3D Viewer</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- The Viewer JS & CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v7.*" type="text/css">
  <script language="JavaScript" src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v7.*"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src='/images/forge-logo.png' style="height:auto;width:20%;position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;z-index:233">
  <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>

  <!-- Developer JS -->
  <script>
      var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
      var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
      var options = {
          'env' : 'Local',
          'document': 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/model2024-01-03-05-50-01-d41d8cd98f00b204e980098ecf8427e/objects/0.svf'
         }; 
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
        viewer.start(options.document, options);
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, in the html mentioned above,
'document': 'http://developer-autodesk.github.io/translated-models/dwfx-sample-house/f0224dd3-8767-45c1-ff99-5c9c881b9fee/0.svf'
If we replace it with , the sample house will be displayed.

The html I used for reference is below.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample.

How can I display the SVF files uploaded to the OSS bucket?
Is it impossible in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

First, All APS APIs, including OSS API, require a valid access token to access the files/objects stored inside it, i.e.

```html
 <!-- Developer JS -->
  <script>
      var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
      var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
      var options = {
          'env' : 'AutodeskProduction',
          'document': ' .... ',
          accessToken: 'YOUR_APS_ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE'
         }; 
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
        viewer.start(options.document, options);
      });
  </script>
```

However ...

I think you misused APS OSS API, APS OSS Bucket is designed to store source model files (e.g. RVT, DWG, NWD, IFC, PDF, etc) temporally before using other APS APIs collaboratively. It's not designed for serving static files, although APS OSS is built on the top of the AWS S3.

If you want to do so, I would advise you to use other cloud storage (e.g., AWS S3, or Azure Blob, etc ...) or your own Web Server serving static files.